# Subprocess results in "Broken Pipe" error

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, subprocess

I'm playing around with socket programming. In the following code snippet I'm trying to connect to client and if his input contains "hack" it will remove it and run shell command and sends back the output.

server side:

```
import socket

class SP:

    def server(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9999))
            s.listen(1)
            while True:
                try:
                    c, addr = s.accept()
                    print('Got connection from ', addr)
                    while True:
                        data = c.recv(1024)
                        if data:
                            if 'hack' in data.decode('utf-8'):
                                import subprocess
                                data = data.decode('utf-8')
                                data = data.strip('hack').lstrip().rstrip()
                                output = subprocess.call(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                                s.send(str(output).encode('utf-8'))

                            else:
                                d = data.decode('utf-8')
                                print('Got data: '+str(d))
                                c.send(str('ACK: '+str(d)+' ...').encode('utf-8'))

                        else:
                            print('No more data from client: '+str(addr))
                            break
                finally:
                    s.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Caught Exception: '+str(e))
            s.close()

obj = SP()
obj.server()
```

client-side:

```
import socket

class CS:

    def client(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9999))
            while True:
                data = input('Enter data to be sent to server: \n')
                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
                    reply = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                    print(str(reply))
            else:
                s.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Caught Exception: '+ str(e))
            s.close()

obj = CS()
obj.client()
```

How can I resolve this the error ? `Caught Exception: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` doesn't tell me much.

**update:**

```
import socket

class SP:

    def server(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9999))
            s.listen(1)
            while True:
                try:
                    c, addr = s.accept()
                    print('Got connection from ', addr)
                    while True:
                        data = c.recv(1024)
                        if data:

                            if 'hack' in data.decode('utf-8'):
                                import subprocess
                                data = data.decode('utf-8')
                                data = data.strip('hack').lstrip().rstrip()
                                print(data)
                                #output = subprocess.call(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                                s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

                            else:
                                d = data.decode('utf-8')
                                print('Got data: '+str(d))
                                c.send(str('ACK: '+str(d)+' ...').encode('utf-8'))

                        else:
                            print('No more data from client: '+str(addr))
                            break
                finally:
                    s.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Caught Exception: '+str(e))
            s.close()

obj = SP()
obj.server()
```

Even when I comment out the line where I call `subprocess.call` I still get "Broken Pipe" so the error isn't originating from the `subprocess` call.

Comment: the issue would get clearer if you post your client as well

Comment: hope the updated post helps

Comment: could you also post the sequence of actions and events, for example which logs do you see on server and client and when? particularly, do you see this output `print(str(reply))` on client side?

Comment: @mangusta  yes, all code is covered. All executes just fine as long as I don't try to use "hack xyz" in the output. All input is being transmitted onto other side as expected but I was hoping for being able to run commands on the other side if I use the keyword "hack" but getting broken pipe error for some reason.

Comment: so you see `Got connection from <addr>` on server, then you see `Enter data to be sent to server: \n` on client, then you enter `hack xyz` on client, then you see `hack xyz` printed on client, and then you see exception on server?

Comment: Correct, I get everything printed out. When I insert `print` function just before the line where I'm calling the `call` method from `subprocess` and it prints out the right thing which is command that I want to run on the other side and receive output.

Comment: The call is commented out but the error persists. Post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using server's socket `s` instead of client's socket `c` to send the data to the client:
`s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))`

how about changing it to:
`c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Ohh ... gosh .... I've been passing the server's socket object instead of client's.